# HTML editor embedded in admin page

Tags: php, jquery, html, wysiwyg, jqte

I'm working on a simple webpage for a company and the company wants to be able to edit the content themselves from time to time. However they have no programing knowledge and therefore I want to use an embedded HTML editor, I have chosen [jQuery TE](http://www.jqueryte.com/).

The problem is that I only know how to use this as a form, e.g.:

```
<form id = "wyForm" method="post" action="test.php">
    <textarea class="editor"name = "testText">Hi</textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="wymupdate" />
</form>
```

Then I would convert the textarea to an editor with jQuery:

```
<script> $('.editor').jqte() </script>
```

This makes it possible to send the result to a .php page that updates the database. However many times I don't want to use a textfield or a form, but just a simple  object that I convert to an editor in the same way. But how do I save the change in that case?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a form? That seems like a logical way of doing this. If you want an action to execute on submit (i.e. firing another PHP file) then you should use a form.

Comment: What would be the purpose of not using a form?  You mean you wanna ajax submit it?  Without it being a form element?

Comment: I was planning on using <span> or <p> instead as I want the user to be able to toggle the edit-mode by a button. In that case, the user sees a text (e.g. in a span) and is then able to press "edit" (which transforms the span to a jQuerty TE field) to edit that span. The user can then save by using a save button. 

If it is a text field, the user can already before pressing the button edit the text, but have to press the button to use the jQuerty TE. This becomes very confusing and uggly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch the form submit event and copy the content to a hidden field.

```
<form id = "wyForm" method="post" action="test.php">
    <div class="editor" name="testText">Hi</div>
    <input type="submit" class="wymupdate" />
    <input type="hidden" id="editorHiddenField" />
</form>
```

...

```
$('#wyForm').submit(function() {
   $('#editorHiddenField').val($('.editor').html());
});
```

You may need to use an API to get the content instead (I'm not familiar with the plugin), but the concept is sound.

**Edit** - If you don't want to use a form *at all*:

```
<div class="editor></div>
<button id="SaveButton">Save</button>
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#SaveButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('savepage.php', { data: $('.editor').html() }).done(function() { alert('saved!'); });
    });
});
```

Comment: My main concern is that I do not want to use a form, but a <span> or <p>. Otherwise I agree that your method is valid, you might even on the submit execute a $.post to alter the database which is desirable in my case

Comment: Yes that actually helps alot! I was having problems with figuring out how to get the content, but I see you are using .html() and that works. However now I get the content like: &It;strong&gt;Hello&it;/strong&gt; instead of <strong>Hello</strong>, do you know why? Thanks alot!

Comment: It may have to do with how the plugin works. `html()` may not be what you're looking for. There has to be a way though, so I'd recommend checking the docs for examples on how to get the content.

Comment: True. I also just realized that if you use .html(), changes made in the jQuerty TE field will not appear in those methods. It will still show the original message in the <span>. However if you use .val() it works and it captures the changes instantly! Regarding the docs it doesn't provide you with any help, it is very minimalistic